# самец машинистки

Tags: одним-словом

Как называется мужчина, чья профессия - печатать на машинке?

Comment: Стрекотун? Машинописец? Оператор машинного письма? Начальник отдела безопасности?

Comment: Только почему самец? Как-то совсем неуважительно к человеку.

Comment: @petajamaja похоже на "самец черной вдовы" ... сожрала и дальше печатает, в ожидании появления маленьких машинистиков :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Это может показаться странным, но слово, которое Вы ищите - это **машинист**.

Согласно [Толковому Словарю Ожегова](http://www.ozhegov.com/words/15457.shtml):

> МАШИНИСТ, -а, м. 1. Механик, управляющий транспортной или другой
>   самодвижущейся машиной, механическим устройством. М. горного комбайна.
>   М. сцены (в театре). 2. Специалист по вождению поездов. М локомотива.
>   3. Специалист, печатающий на машинке.

В данном случае, Вас интересует значение (3).

Comment: Как в таком случае зовется самка того машиниста, который в словаре Ожегова под номером (1)? Машинистка?

Comment: @cha Я думаю, что просто _машинист_.